# Implementing Three.js SSAOPass in AFrame

Tags: html, three.js, aframe, webvr, post-processing

I was able to successfully integrate Threejs Effect composer in aframe as a component by exporting everything as THREE.Effectcomposer, THREE.SSAOPass etc. and adding the effect inside a aframe component and i tweaked the AFrame renderer to update the effects in the scene. OutlinePass from threejs worked fine in this code but SSAO is not working and i don't get any errors. Please someone help me figure out the problem. the code for SSAOPass looks like this

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('ssao', {

  init: function () {
    this.el.addEventListener('that', evt => this.onEnter());
    this.el.addEventListener('mouseleave', evt => this.onLeave());
    setTimeout(() => this.el.emit("that"), 2000);
  },
  onEnter: function () {
    const scene = this.el.sceneEl.object3D;
    const camera = this.el.sceneEl.camera;
    const renderer = this.el.sceneEl.renderer;
    const render = renderer.render;
    const composer = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer);
    //let renderPass = new THREE.RenderPass(scene, camera);
    //let outlinePass = new THREE.OutlinePass(new THREE.Vector2(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight), scene, camera);
    const ssaoPass = new THREE.SSAOPass( scene, camera, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    //composer.addPass(renderPass);
    //composer.addPass(outlinePass);
    ssaoPass.kernelRadius = 16;
        composer.addPass( ssaoPass );
    // let objects = [];
    // this.el.object3D.traverse(node => {
    //   if (!node.isMesh) return;
    //   objects.push(node);
    // });
    // outlinePass.selectedObjects = objects;
    // outlinePass.renderToScreen = true;
    // outlinePass.edgeStrength = this.data.strength;
    // outlinePass.edgeGlow = this.data.glow;
    // outlinePass.visibleEdgeColor.set(this.data.color);
    // HACK the AFRAME render method (a bit ugly)
    const clock = new THREE.Clock();
    this.originalRenderMethod = render;
    let calledByComposer = false;
        renderer.render = function () {
      if (calledByComposer) {
        render.apply(renderer, arguments);
      } else {
        calledByComposer = true;
        composer.render(clock.getDelta());
        calledByComposer = false;
      }
    };
  },
  onLeave: function () {
    this.el.sceneEl.renderer.render = this.originalRenderMethod;
  },
  remove: function () {
    this.onLeave();
  }
});
```

I have also created a glitch project which i am sharing here. Please feel free to join and collaborate in my project
Edit link: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/accessible-torpid-partridge
Site link:https://accessible-torpid-partridge.glitch.me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please update the Glitch link? I'm curious to see how you got OutlinePass and EffectComposer working in A-Frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct, all you need is to tweak the exposed `SSAOShader` uniforms: 
`SSAOPass.kernelRadius`, `SSAOPass.minDistance`, `SSAOPass.maxDistance` - like in the [Three.js example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=ssa#webgl_postprocessing_ssao).

Keep in mind - the scale in the example is huge, so the values will need to be different in a default aframe scene.

It's a good idea to be able to dynamically update a component (via `setAttribute()` if you [properly handle updates](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html#handling-property-updates)), so you can see what's going on in realtime. Something like I did here - [SSAO in a-frame](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/ssao-hacked/) (also based on Don McCurdys [gist](https://gist.github.com/donmccurdy/31560945d5723737e6c656a2974ab628).

I've used some basic HTML elements, most threejs examples use [dat.GUI](https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui) - it is made for demo / debug tweaks.

Comment: This is great can you please give me access to your code for SSAO Implementation so that I can see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: In the top left corner there should be a "source code" hyperlink

Comment: Also how do we reduce the splotchy occlusion and make it smooth same like in threejs?

Comment: The source code is private i guess. I'm getting 404 erro in github when i click that link. But i was successfully able to see your code by viewing page source.

Comment: @KarthickME sorry, my browser cached a 'working version' :P It should be working now, the file is [here](https://github.com/gftruj/webzamples/blob/master/aframe/ssao-hacked/index.html)

Comment: Can we change the smoothness of AO somehow? Is it beacuse of scale or AFrame?